# Android -- Record video with aac audio encoding

Tags: android, video, html5-video

I am trying to record a video, using the camera app, by using the suggested code from Android's documentation.

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/videobasics.html

Is there any ways i can control/specify the audio encoding, as an extra with the intent.